# Add server controls to a page that have no form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have A single page that has the following structure

```
<form runat="server"><placeholder></placeholder></form>
```

I have a control call 'feed' that gets added to the placeholder. The control that gets added, holds multiple other controls called 'product'.

I load the products into the feed dynamically with ajax.

The problem is, that the mark-up in the product control contains server side buttons that require a form tag with runat=server. Otherwise the page wont compile.

The page compiles fine once I add the necessary form tags to the 'product' control. This is not satisfactory as I don't want multiple form tags on the page at once.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you post a more comprehensive example?  Don't see why you need the form tags in each product control since you have a wrapper form tag that is runat=server.  What error do you get etc...?  What does the product control look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add a single `<form runat=server>` that wraps all server controls or don't use server controls (normal html tags).

Or, use a more flexible framework like MVC that gives you full control of your markup.

Comment: Thanks I just changed the asp buttons to html buttons.